# Database handling in applications

Tags: c#, mysql, oop

This is a bit of difficult question to ask but *any* feedback at all is welcome.

Ill start by the background, I am a university student studying software engineering last year we covered c# and I got myself a job working in a software house coding prototype software in c# (their main language is c++ using QT) after producing the prototype it was given to some clients which have all passed back positive feedback.

Now I am looking at the app and thinking well I could use this as a showcase with my CV esp as the clients who used the software have said that they will sign something to reference it.

So if I am going to do that then I had better get it right and do it to the best I possibly can. so I have started to look at it and think where I can improve it and one of the ways in which I think that I can is the way it handles the database connections and the data along with it.

the app itself runs along side a MySQL server and there is 6 different schemas which it gets its data from.

I have written a class (called it databaseHandler) which has the mysqlconnection in it ( one question was about if the connection should remain open the whole time the app is running, or open it fire a query then close it etc) inside this class I have written a method which takes some arguments and creates its query string which it then does the whole mysqlDataReader = cmd.executeReader(), this then returns the reader back to where ever it was called from.

After speaking to a friend he mentioned it might be nice if the method returned the raw data and not the reader, therefore keeping all the database "stuff" away from the main app.

After playing around I managed to find a couple of tutorials on putting the reader data into arrays and arraylists and passing then back, also had a go at passing back an array list of hashtables - these methods obv mean that the dev must know the column names in order to find the correct data.

then I stumbled across a page which went on about creating a Class which had the attributes of the column names and created a list which you could pull your data from:

http://zensoftware.org/archives/248 is the link

so this made me think, in order to use this method, would I need to create 6 classes with the attributes of the columns of my tables ( a couple of tables has up to 10-15 columns)? or is there a better way for me to handle my data?

I am not really clued up on these things but if pointed in the right direction I am a very fast learner :)

Again I thank you for any input what so ever.

Vade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of ideas that are very close but are pretty common problems, but good that you are actively thinking about how to handle them!

On the question about leaving the connection open for the whole program or only having it open during the actual query time. The common (and proper) way to do this is only have the connection open as much as you need it, so

```
MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(yourConnectionString);

//Execute your queries

cn.close();
```

This is better since you don't risk leaving open connections, or having transaction issues typing up databases and resources.

With the having just the data returned and not the actual datareader this is a good idea but by just returning the data as an ArrayList or whatever you are kind of losing the structure of the data a little.

A good way to do this would be to either have your class just take the datareader to populate it's data OR have the Data Layer just return  an instance of your class after reading the data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it would be an excellent approach if your data access class returned a custom class populated with data from the database. That would be object-oriented. Instead of, say, returning a DataSet or an array containing customer information, you would create a Customer class with properties. Then, when you retrieve the data from the database, you populate an instance of the Customer class with the data, and return it to the calling code.

A lot of the newer Microsoft technologies are focusing on making this task easier. Quite often, there are many more than 6 classes needed, and writing all that code can seem like drudgery. I would suggest that, if you are interested in learning about those newer approaches, and possibly adapting them to your own code, you can check out [Linq to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) and [Entity Framework](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

> one question was about if the connection should remain open the whole
>   time the app is running, or open it fire a query then close it etc

You want to keep the connection open as little as possible. Therefore you should open on each data request and close it as soon as you are done. You should also dispose it but if your database stuff is inside a C# using statement that happens automatically.

As far as the larger question on how to return the data to your application you are on the right track. You typically want to hide the raw database from the rest of your application and mapping the raw data to other intermediate classes is the correct thing to do.

Now, how you do this mapping is a very large topic. Ideally you don't want to create classes that map one to one your tables/columns but rather provide your app a more app-friendly representation of the data (e.g. business objects rather than database tables.)  For example, if your employee data is split in to or three tables for normalization purposes you can hide this complexity and present the information as a single Employee class that binds the data from the other tables together.

Answer (score 0):

Abstracting away your data access code using objects is known as [Object/Relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). It's actually a much more complex task than it appears at first sight. There are several libraries, even in the framework itself, that already do very well what you're trying to implement.

If your needs are *very* simple, look into typed DataSets. They let you create the table classes in a designer and also generate objects that will do the loading and saving for you (given certain limitations)

If your needs are less simple, but still pretty simple, I recommend you take a look at Linq To SQL to see if it covers your needs, as it does table-class mapping in a very straightforward way and uses a more modern usage pattern than DataSets.

There are also more complex ORMs that allow you to define more complex mappings, like Entity Framework or nHibernate, but very often their complexity is not necessary.

Details like connection lifetime will then depend on your specific needs. Sometimes it's best to keep the connection open, if you have a lot of queries caused by user interaction, like is usually the case with a desktop app. Other times it's best to keep them as short as possible to avoid congestion, like the case of web apps.

Whichever technology you choose will likely end up guiding you onto a good set of practices for it, and the best you can do is try things out and see which works best for you.